# Truncate number while formatting in DataWeave

Tags: formatting, mule, dataweave

Is there any shorter way of truncating a number while formating it? Looks like the default behavior is rounding. By now I have this:

```
var val = 123.129
---
{
    def: val as String {format: "0.00"},
    truncate: 
        (if(val > 0) (floor(val * 100)/100)
        else (ceil(val * 100)/100)
        ) as String {format: "0.00"}
}
```

and the output is

```
{
  "def": "123.13",
  "truncate": "123.12"
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define the round mode in the type conversion:

```
down: 123.129 as String {format: "0.00", roundMode:"DOWN" }
```

The modes are base on the names of https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/RoundingMode.html.

Another option is to do what you did but encapsulate it into a reusable function:

```
fun truncate(n,p) = do {
    var power = 10 pow p
    ---
    if (n>0) floor(n * power)/power
    else ceil(n * power)/power
}
```

Comment: I found a supported method using roundMode. Answer updated.